# How to work with register_globals off on PHP

Tags: php

I use global variables on my website such `GET,POST,FILES,SESSION`. I wrote my website on a server where `register_globals is on`. And i just moved my website to another server where `register_globals is off` and i actually do not know how to deal with it.

For exmaple, i have this code:

```
$do = $_GET['do'];
```

or

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

How i understood, i can not do this, php can't extract this data. How can i change my code to receive data from GET,POST,SESSION,FILES?

Thank you

Comment: Why wouldn't You do this? You *can* do `$name = $_POST['name']`.

Comment: why can't you do it? Just because register_globals is off doesn't mean _GET/_POST and the other superglobals magically disappear. They never depended on register_globals.

Answer (score 7):

You misunderstand. `$_GET` & co are [superglobals](http://php.net/language.variables.superglobals) which are always available and cannot be disabled, your code will always work.

register_globals makes those `$_GET` values directly available as variables. I.e. instead of `$_GET['do']` you could use `$do`.

Comment: Thank you, but actually it doesn't work. I use this simple example when accesing index.php?do=123 to check: `if(isset($_GET['do'])) {echo "yes";}` and i don't receive any result

Comment: That's not a problem with register_globals though.

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to access the vars and works with `register_globals_gpc = off`:

```
$do = $_GET['do'];
```

If `register_globals_gpc = on` the `$_GET` would automatically be extracted and this would work:

```
echo $do;
```

So if you are doing it the way you show then all is well.  `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, as well as `$_SERVER` and `$_SESSION` are already superglobal and available anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and easy way would be using `extract` function.

```
extract($_POST);
extract($_GET);
extract($_COOKIES);
```

But this is **VERY VERY VERY BAD** from security and maintainablity aspect! You should rewrite the code, if possible, to:

```
$variable = $_POST['variable'];
..
```

Answer (score 1):

when I googled this issue and open the very first serch result it gave me [the solution](http://mrphp.com.au/blog/how-enable-register-globals-php-5#.U1p2R1SSzh8). Try this, Hope it will work for you